# R barplot not showing xlab

Tags: r, bar-chart

I am using `igraph` and I want to plot the degree distribution of a graph. Here is an example:

```
full <- graph.full(20, directed=FALSE)
full_deg = degree.distribution(full)
barplot(full_deg, main='Full graph', xlab='Degree')
```

I get this picture, but the numbers from the x axis are missing.

[image: r plot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer's in the barplot documentation (`?barplot`). Just add `names.arg = 1:20` to your barplot. You can decrease `cex.names` slightly to allow all items to be displayed.

```
barplot(abs(rnorm(20)), names.arg=1:20, xlab='Degree', cex.names=0.8)
```